# Can a killed ALTER TABLE statement leave an index partially built?

Tags: mysql, innodb

We started an ALTER TABLE which dropped one index and added another.  Although we were only expecting the table to be locked for writes, reads started queueing up, so we killed the ALTER process.  But when the KILL finished, the old index was gone, and the new index was there in its place, with a much lower cardinality than expected.

Searching on the table seems to be faster now, so it seems like the ALTER went through fine, but we're not sure.  Is it possible that our KILL has left the index in a partially-built stage?

Comment: one thing to be aware of is innodb estimates cardinalities: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/28/why-innodb-index-cardinality-varies-strangely/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the index is there you may assume that it is complete.

You can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` or `SHOW INDEXES` to see the indexes on the table.

As noted in the comments, the cardinality listed by `SHOW INDEXES` is just an estimate.

One test you can try is to run `SHOW INDEXES`, then run `ANALYZE TABLE`, then run `SHOW INDEXES` again and see how the estimated cardinality value changes.

Answer (score 1):

By your description (both reads/writes locked) you are most likely using an older version of InnoDB, or adding an index to a column in utf8 character set.

Here is how it works in your version:

1. Empty table is created with the new table definition.
2. Rows are copied 1 after the other from old table to new table (new indexes are also created).
3. Once copy is complete, old table is deleted, new table is renamed.

(If you cancel between steps 2&3 the new table is just safely removed.)

For full disclosure - here is how it works in InnoDB plugin (default for MySQL 5.5, available from 5.1+):

1. Table is read through to find data for the index, and written to a temporary file.
2. The temporary file is sorted.
3. The index is created by inserting the data in order.

(This method is more optimized.  InnoDB calls is "fast-index creation".)